# select value of an element which has a namespace assigned

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-stylesheet

i'm trying to do a simple xsl transformation on an edifabric x12 xml file.
How can i select the `<D_744_1>` Element?

Sample XML:

```
<INTERCHANGE xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="www.edifabric.com/x12">
    <S_ISA>
        <D_744_1>00</D_744_1>
    </S_ISA> 
</INTERCHANGE>
```

Sample XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <testfield><xsl:value-of select="INTERCHANGE/S_ISA/D_744_1" /></testfield>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testfield/>
```

Desired Result:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <testfield>00</testfield>
```

updated answer thanks **@ChriPf**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:edi="www.edifabric.com/x12" exclude-result-prefixes="edi">

    <xsl:template match="edi:INTERCHANGE">
        <testfield><xsl:value-of select="edi:S_ISA/edi:D_744_1" /></testfield>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: could you please insert the desired result too to show what the problem was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution could look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:edi="www.edifabric.com/x12">
  <xsl:template match="edi:D_744_1">
    <xsl:element name="testfield">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have a default namespace in your xml, you have to define it in the xsl as well. Find some more information e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms950779.aspx).

Comment: the result looks strange. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>00 it has no xml element around the value

Comment: strange when i try it on http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php or on http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html or on http://markbucayan.appspot.com/xslt/index.html i do either get an error or the result does not have xml elements, just the value 00. Oxygen gives me the same result (no xml element named testfield) :-/

Comment: sorry, i seems the path in match did not work... - however, maybe the solution with selecting only the "D_744_1"-field gives the desired result - just not sure if this is enough for your case

Comment: that's much better :) any chance to remove all namespaces of the result?